# Is it necessary to apply and auto apply security updates on ubuntu 18.04 (and 14.04, 16.04)

Tags: updates, security

[there are ways to automatically install ubuntu security updates](https://websiteforstudents.com/setup-automatic-security-updates-on-ubuntu-17-04-17-10/)

or to [manually apply them](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-security-updates-ubuntu/)

the question for me, is it actually necessary for a productive server?

as automatically applying updates can break the server as well unexpectedly

so what do you guys have setup on your servers related to security updates?

Comment: It's up to you, it's beneficial to have automatic security updates, but have a 'revert' plan or know how to revert if an update breaks something.  You *should* have automatic security updates enabled where yo ucan (I do on all of mine)

Comment: @ThomasWard just write an answer then. And tell me about your backup plan